# DataTable no corrige encabezados cuando estos se agrandan en la celda

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy haciendo un `DataTable` con 15 elementos, estos valores son retornados desde un endpoint, y al obtener la data, es metida en la `DataTable`. Pero cuando todos cargan, los encabezados no se ajustan al nuevo tamaño de las columnas, si no que debo ordenarlo por algún campo, o buscar, que se arreglan.

```
var all_T = $('#allTransactions').removeAttr('width').DataTable({
    scrollX:        true,
    paging:         true,
    columnDefs: [
        { width: 200, targets: 0 }
    ],
    fixedColumns: false,
    columns: [
        { title: 'Fecha',  targets: 0 },
        {...},//El resto de elementos
        { title: 'Correo', targets: 14 },
    ]
})
all_T.clear();
for(let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++){
    all_T.row.add([
        //Agregar todos los elementos
    ])
all_T.columns.adjust().draw();
}
```

En mi `HTML` tengo la tabla

```
<table style="width:100%" class="display dataTable" id="allTransactions">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Y que queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo ordeno, ya queda como debe de ser...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado simular un click en ese id de la fecha cuando termina de poner todos los datos, y aunque si hace el click y lo ordena, no se ordenan los encabezados, es decir, un humano tiene que hacerlo, por así decirlo.

Y algunas veces se muestra de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y no se que rayos, porque en una tab(la pagina tengo dos tabs que se cargan al mismo tiempo con 2 promesas) tengo la misma información, cambiando un campo, y esa funciona perfectamente con los mismos parametros, mismas columnas, mismo codigo. Pero la otra tab, esta pregunta, no funciona bien

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar un ejemplo de lo que es allData?  Con solo un registro seria suficiente. Por otra parte, no se porque predefines el thead y el tbody. Creo que con solo que pongas el table es suficiente para que luego el datatable se genere.

Answer (score 0):

Usa esto:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
                    $("#allTransactions").DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
                }, 700);
```

Comment: De por sii la tabla tarda un segundo en ser llenada, preferiria no utilizar timeout porque ya es demasiado tiempo el que se tarda, y eso que estoy solo en dev, cuando sea prod será mas cargada seguramente

Comment: Puedes usarla instrucción sin el timeout, yo la tengo así porque en un inicio en mi ventana la tabla esta oculta

Comment: El `.columns.adjust().draw()` Sii lo he agregado, pero sin exito alguno

Comment: Los dataTables tienen una propiedad "initComplete" a esta propiedad se le asigna una función que se ejecuta cuando a terminado la carga de datos. La instrucción .columns.adjust().draw(); debe ir ahi, si no nunca te funcionara.

Comment: Ahorita sii lo tiene, pero el problema persiste

Comment: Si eso no esta en la publicación, no te puedo ayudar